# Address locator alternative for ArcGIS Online

Tags: arcgis-online, geolocation, address

I do not have a license for ArcGIS Server.

I created an address locator using my county's centerline data. I edited my school boundaries so they "snapped" to those centerlines. Now when I do population analysis I can know that my selections of geolocated students are in the right boundary. Great! Now lets make a webmap for families to search and find their home schools! Found [Here](http://sanjuan.maps.arcgis.com/apps/InformationLookup/index.html?appid=ce5d1d9c30a142788b6358683b434d50)

ISSUE:  The Esri geocoder is different "off" from my centerlines in a few places.  On a few streets, where the attendance boundaries should go down the middle of the streets, it is telling families the wrong school because the (polygon) boundary is a few feet over the centerline.

Example: 10741 FAIR OAKS BLVD, FAIR OAKS 95628 was an address of concern. The app pop up says the wrong school because of variation from county centerlines used to create the boundaries and the ArcGIS map.

WHAT I WANT TO DO:  Use a "free" or very cheap locator that I can create using my already made address locator or something open I can edit when issues on a few street arise.  I want to add this as the address search bar in my app.

Is this possible? If so, how?  Details needed, I have very basic Python experience and am the only GIS professional at my job.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the data for the missing locator you could set up a layer with the addresses to do a feature search in the map and have that used in the WAB app you create. 
You could setup the feature layer as completely transparent if you want the same experience with the geocoder.

http://doc.arcgis.com/en/web-appbuilder/create-apps/widget-query.htm